# Range.find() correct coding in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find in a column of numbers the first number bigger than some fixed number, say 6.

Please can you tell me what do I need to put in the 'what' argument of the .find function to do that?

If the 'what' argument only accepts single values, how would I code what I want to do?

Thanks

Comment: are numbers in column ordered (ascending or descending)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on context, i wouldn't use find, i would use a do until loop.

```
dim i as long
i = 1
do until cells(i,1).value > 6
    i = i+1
loop
'something with cells(i,1).value
```

This would work when going down a column, as presented, or could be modified for across a row.

---

Edit1:  was originally going to make this not an open ended loop, in case you don't have a result... lr would be used to find the last row of data in the column:

```
dim i as long, lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
i = 1
do until cells(i,1).value > 6 OR i > lr 
    i = i+1
loop
if i > lr then exit sub
'something with cells(i,1).value
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: @cyril thanks but am a bit confused. You've defined lr as (I think) the first row of the column (the column is fully populated), but then not done anything with it.

Comment: @Napolean sorry, forgot to take that line out.  you don't need lr at all.  Was going to have there be 2 conditions, in case you hit the end of the last row and didn't have any result.

Comment: or did you mean to start i=1r?

Comment: @Napolean just updated the answer with that addition

Comment: Maybe `do while cells(i,1).value <= 6 AND i <= lr` and change the comment to `'do something with cells(i,1).value if i<=lr`

Comment: @Jeeped I can see the do while being useful, though I chose the do until route (post lists bigger than 6, so didn't use >=).  I believe it could be possible that the last row could have the result, though we would want to specify  *OR i > lr* which might do the trick.

Comment: @Jeeped added that or i>lr and put in if i>lr exit sub, which should fit the bill.